Undefined Symbol - Issue when building a project with EMCC
I am trying to compile with EMCC (EMSCRIPTEN) a c++ project built on top of IfcOpenShell ( a c++ library, here some references Installation Github).
it's my first time doing it so I had lots of issues, but now seems I am close to run my program on the web, the issue I am facing now comes when I include some cpp files included in the 'ifcgeom' folder for the emcc compiler.
in these cpp files there are some 'include' statements which includes headers from Open Cascade, but the compiler returns error with a lot of error like the following:
undefined symbol: gp_Dir::Angle(gp_Dir const&) const
undefined symbol: gp_Dir2d::Angle(gp_Dir2d const&) const
undefined symbol: TopExp::MapShapes(TopoDS_Shape const&, TopAbs_ShapeEnum, NCollection_IndexedMap<TopoDS_Shape, TopTools_ShapeMapHasher>&)
undefined symbol: TopExp_Explorer::TopExp_Explorer(TopoDS_Shape const&, TopAbs_ShapeEnum, TopAbs_ShapeEnum)
undefined symbol: TopExp_Explorer::Next()

etc...
These methods are declared in header files (hxx) and have an inline definition in .lxx files (usually imported in the hxx files), but seems the compiler is not getting correctly the definition, or I am missing something.
if I try setting the flag ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 I get the following errors:
undefined symbol: typeinfo for Standard_Failure
undefined symbol: typeinfo for Standard_Transient
undefined symbol: typeinfo for Geom_Surface
undefined symbol: typeinfo for Geom_Plane
undefined symbol: typeinfo for Geom_Surface

I am including (using the -I flag) all the needed header directories..
In order to compile my project files I am using all the needed cpp from the ifcopenshell library, so at this point I really don't know what to do, maybe I am missing something about Emscripten/emcc...
EDIT: the definitions of Open Cascade headers declarations are not always implemented, I found that checking in OpenCascade github repository, all the methods are implemented in .cxx files (Open Cascade Github Repo ), but in IfcOpenShell OpenCascade Dependency, there are not cxx files, so the error makes sense to me, but now I don't get why I can compile with the default Visual Studio Compiler without errors, while EMCC is facing these issues.
Still investigating

Does this answer your question? What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?

What does 'usually imorted in the hxx files' mean? If they are inline definitions why not place them directly in the hxx files. That would be the normal C++ thing to do, but perhaps emscripten changes things in some way I don't know about.

You don't include some cpp files. You include header files....

@john the '.lxx' files with definitions are included in the .hxx file, I think the same as you, but seems OpenCascade headers are just like this by default..

The statement about inlining is incorrect - listed methods are NOT defined in .lxx header files and require project to be linked against libraries like -lTKMath and others. Please share details about your project and it's building scripts.
